# Action invoked without dispatching it - Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to understand redux and is having some doubts regarding mapDispatchToProps.

The code is as follows.

```
import * as actions  from '../../redux/actions';
import './style.scss'

class Center extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCenters();
  }

  ...
}
export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.center,
}),{
  ...actions,
})(Center);
```

Actions file is defined as follows.

```
export const getCenters = () => ({
  type: types.CENTERS_REQUEST,
});
```

When the component is mounted, this.props.getCenters() is called and the action is dispatched and everything works as expected.

The question is,

**There is no dispatch mentioned in the definition of getCenters. So, how is this action invoked without dispatching it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux injects `dispatch` (Implicitly) to your actions in `connect`:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.center,
}),{
  ...actions,
})(Center);
```

If we abstract this a bit, we can watch how it happens (Explicitly):

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        getCenters: () => dispatch(getCenters())
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  ...state.center,
}), mapDispatchToProps)(Center);
```

As a result, getCenters gets equipped with `dispatch`.